# Some pages are not loading public assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

my assets are in my public folder and whenever I open the index page of my scaffold it loads well

[image]

but whenever I open any other page (such as show, new or edit) it doesn't load my assets.

[image]

here is my development config file

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true
  if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
    config.action_controller.enable_fragment_cache_logging = true
    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end
  config.active_storage.service = :local
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.quiet = true
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
  config.hosts << "8342f8b743074610bd0c08989dee0747.vfs.cloud9.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
end
```

My application controller looks like this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
end
```

and post controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:name, :about, :desc, :other)
    end
end
```

this is how the console looks like
[image]

what can be wrong please?

Comment: what does you `application_controller.rb` look like, can you post that code in the question too?  When you inspect the page where the assets aren;t loading do you see any errors?  If you open the source code view I assume the files ar enot loaded at all, correct?

Comment: I suspect the layout for the other pages is not linked properly to the layout.

Answer (score -1):

Check your layout or fragment where you link to the application javascript, looks like you're linking to js/app.js instead of /js/app.js . Same for the images.

Best practice is to use Rails' javascript and stylesheet link helpers and maybe put them all in a partial, like _page_head.html.erb and require this in all relevant layouts.

Don't worry about these little snags, Rails is a great framework and you'll get the hang of it.